# fill randomly 4 time a grid in java with letter

Tags: java, random, grid

Good evening, I have to fill in a grid that I created by adding 4 random letters in it.
I don't know how to get started, I have an array [i=5][j=4] and I have to add to a random i and j a G and that 4 times.
I am aware of having to use Math.random() as well as a while(x<4) but I don't know how to go about it.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFpY7.png)

```js
package tp1;

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.Math;

public class Joueur {

  //attributs

  String pseudo;
  private char[][] grille;
  private int nbreManches;
  private int nbreObstacles;

  //constructeurs

  public Joueur(String valeur) {

    nbreManches = 0;
    nbreObstacles = 0;
    grille = new char[5][4];
    pseudo = valeur;

  }

  public Joueur() {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Quel est votre pseudo ?");
    pseudo = sc.nextLine();
    nbreManches = 0;
    nbreObstacles = 0;
    grille = new char[5][4];

  }

  public void afficher() {

    grille = new char[5][4];
    System.out.println("************************************");
    System.out.println("Pseudo: " + pseudo);
    System.out.println("Nombre de manches: " + nbreManches);
    System.out.println("Nombres d'obstacles: " + nbreObstacles);
    System.out.println();


    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        System.out.print("|");
      }
      System.out.println("|");
    }
    System.out.println();


  }


}
```

Comment: I like to read code written in French. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know from your description where in the grid you want the letters to be, but I can give this hints:

- `Math.random()` is always in the range 0 <= x < 1. If you want a number 0 <= x <= y you multiply `Math.random()` with y + 1 and convert it to `int`. (conversion to `int` truncates the number, so for example truncate(0.999 * 25) will always be < 24, hence +1)
- Datatype `char` is also a number, you can apply numeric operations on it.

Knowing this and that the alphabet has 26 characters you can write:

```java
    private static char randomLetter() {
        int i = (int) (Math.random() * 26); // 0 ... 25
        int j = (int) (Math.random() * 2); // upper case yes/no
        if (j == 1) {
            return (char) ('A' + i);
        }
        return (char) ('a' + i);
    }
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: it's not that but I learned something thanks to you ! 
in my table I have to add 4 letters (the same) in order to gray boxes. as in the picture below
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/992110146048241687/1028473737030418502/unknown.png

Comment: I cannot open that link

Comment: http://www.noelshack.com/2022-40-7-1665279593-unknown.png

Comment: I think I understand now. I would 1) initialize the grid, 2) calculate random indexes like `int randI = (int) (Math.random() * 5);`, set the 'G' into it and 3) print it.
The positions in the grid you can access (read or write) through `grille[i][j]`.

Comment: yes with random il have à random i and random j so the G can be in one of the 30 case of the grid

Comment: can u help me for replace |  per □ or G because thanks to u i have a random i and an random j but idk how to write "write □ in the new i j of the grid"

Comment: You can assign a value to an array element with the [] operator like so: `grille[ i ][ j ] = <new value>`.

Comment: see also https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html